# Edit KML lines in Illustrator or getting smooth curves

Tags: kml, illustrator, true-curves

I have a problem, when I'm making my traces in an application like Google Earth, I can't make smooth curves, only straight line.

So I thought maybe I should export the trace to Illustrator then modify the curves in it and then export them.

Is this the right way to do it ? How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add more vertices to the line to make it smooth in GoogleEarth without the need to export your data to Illustrator using the following steps:

- Right-click the line in the GoogleEarth

[image]
 - Select the starting vertex that you want to smooth its line segment. It will become blue color

[image]

- Use the digitizer tool to add additional vertices on the line path

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have Adobe Illustrator, but it was relatively straightforward to smooth a kml trajectory with a spline fit in python using the `pykml` module to parse the .kml file and re-write with the modified coordinates. Result shown here:
[image]